# c++ array arguments not working

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

I'm trying to make a function that finds the maximum value of any array, and for some reason the function will not take the array as input (It is for a program that runs through very big numbers, as for the unsigned long ints).

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int findMax();

int main(){
int test[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
findMax(test,6);//Says invalid arguments


return 0;
}

int findMax(int x[],unsigned long int size){
    unsigned long int max = 0;
    unsigned long int newmax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
        x[i] = newmax;
        if(newmax > max) max = newmax;
    }
    return max;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, please feel free to judge anything else that's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype should be consistent with the function definition as follows:

```
int findMax(int [], unsigned long int );
```

also, you can compact your function as follows:

```
int findMax(int x[],unsigned long int size)
{
    unsigned long int max = x[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
        if(x[i] > max) max = x[i];

    return max;
}
```

Lastly, You need to use the value returned from the function so you can write in the main:

```
cout << findMax(test,6);
```

instead of the function only.

Comment: Yes, I know the returned value has to go somewhere, but it was the prototype. Thanks for the compacting advice

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote the forward declaration for `findMax`, you claimed it had no parameters, but then you called it with some.